# Change thread name used to run @StreamListener method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I want to change the name of the thread used for @StreamListener methods as the current name is too long in the logs. I looked in the documentation but couldn't get any info. Is there a way?

Eg. KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='TOPIC_NAME', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}.container-0-C-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a container customizer `@Bean`...

```java
@Bean
public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer() {
    return (container, destinationName, group) -> {
        container.setBeanName(group + "." + destinationName);
    };
}
```

The bean name is used as a prefix for the thread name.